# JCS to Autosys migration

Tags: jobs, autosys, jcs

We have jobs running in `JCS`, and since `JCS` is no longer supported, we are migrating jobs in `JCS` to `Autosys`.
No one in our team have any idea on how to migrate the **JOBs** in `JCS` to `Autosys`. Even I googled for the same but no help.

Can anyone please give steps to migrate `JCS` jobs to `Autosys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about migrating active jobs, but it seems Autosys has a "job information language" (JIL) that can be used to write commands for creating jobs. If JCS has any way to extract the job information into one or more files, you could write a script to parse the JCS job information from the files and the script could construct and run JIL for recreate the job in Autosys.